Tooltip for a 2 dataset doughnut chart is being presented when mouse's rover is out of the dataset placement
I have a doughnut chart implemented with Chart.js 4.4.1. This chart has 2 datasets, one in an outside dataset doughnut, and the other one in the inside dataset doughnut.
Each dataset has his own tooltip. And the tooltip should be presented only when the mouse is rovering on top of the respective dataset.
But this is not what always happens, as shown in the images and GIF below. If I move the mouse on top of the dataset, without leave it, the tooltip is changing the presented data from one dataset to another.



The problem also happens when the mouse is hovering in other positions out of the respective dataset.
The chart code:
chart_pie_sistemas = new Chart(ctx_chart_pie_sistemas, {
    type: "doughnut",
    data: {
        labels: ['Cherwell Service Management - Atendentes', 'SZ.Chat - Omni Channel', 'Google Chat'],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "Sistema",
                data: [10953, 6332, 0],
                backgroundColor: ['#F16A6A', '#2196F3', '#0F9D58'],
            },
            {
                label: "UI",
                data: [0, 0, 17285],
                backgroundColor: ['#F16A6A', '#2196F3', '#0F9D58'],
            },
        ]
    },
    options: {
        locale: 'pt-BR',
        responsive: true,
        interaction: {
            intersect: false,
            mode: 'dataset',
        },
        plugins: {
            legend: {
                display: true,
                position: 'top',
            },
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Notificações por sistema e UI',
                font: {
                    size: 24,
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                filter: function(context) {
                    var valor = context.dataset.data[context.dataIndex];
                    return valor > 0;
                },
                callbacks: {
                    footer: function(context) {
                        let sum = 0;
                        var contador = 0;
                        context.forEach(function(tooltipItem) {
                            contador++;
                            sum += tooltipItem.parsed;
                        });
                        var total_texto = (contador > 1 ? 'Total: ' + formatLocale(sum) : "");
                        return total_texto;
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }
});


Please, refer to this jsfiddle to test the code.
Is it possible to configure this chart to display the correct tooltip, according the mouse hovers placement in the respective dataset?

If you completely remove your interaction settings,  equivalent to (interaction:{intersect: true, mode: "nearest"}) the tooltip only shows one data point, the one for the circular area hovered by the pointer. If this is not what you wanted, please let us know why have you used those settings.  It's true that with intersect: false the results seem to always be wrong, but in order to debug the code we'll need to have  a better understanding of the intended behavior.

The interaction settings were included to have the attribute mode defined as dataset. This because I want to present both data per series, apart sum of data informed in the tooltip (as you can see in the images I sent). The problem, as you pointed out, is the attribute intersect set to false. If I just change  to intersect: true it works perfectly. Thank you for your help.

As commented by @kikon above, the cause of the problem with the tooltip was the attribute intersect set to false. When I changed the value to intersect: true (or just remove the attribute, considering the default value is true) the problem is solved.
Here the jsfiddle with the solution.
Important to say that I declared the interaction group to set the attribute mode: dataset, considering I want my tooltip be unique to all dataset, presenting all data values, plus the sum in the footer, as you can see in the images posted in the question above.
